# How do I set dynamic transformTo values in a Polymer neon-animation?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I want to use neon-animation in Polymer to animate an element from wherever it is (it is draggable and movable) to the middle of the screen. And to do that I think I need to dynamically set `transformTo` depending on where the element is on the screen and where it should move to.

However, it seems that `animationConfig` gets evaluated only once.

Is there a way to dynamically set or evaluate 1px, 2px and 3px in the example below?

```
properties: {
  animationConfig: {
    value: function() {
      return {
        name: 'transform-animation',
        node: this,
        transformFrom: 'translate3d(0,0,0)',
        transformTo: 'translate3d(1px,2px,3px)',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a good way to do it, but instead found a workaround.

I override the `getAnimationConfig(type)` method, which is called by neon-animation each time an animation is performed.

**Note** that the result from `getAnimationConfig` must be an array!

```
getAnimationConfig: function() {
  var x = 1;
  var y = 2;
  var z = 3;
  return [{
    name: 'transform-animation',
    node: this,
    transformFrom: 'translate3d('+x+'px,'+y+'px,'+z+'px)',
    transformTo: 'translate3d(0,0,0)'
  }]
}
```